# How to change SparkContext properties in Interactive PySpark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I change spark.driver.maxResultSize in pyspark interactive shell? I have used the following code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = (SparkConf()
    .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "10g"))
sc.stop()
sc=SparkContext(conf)
```

but it gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'SparkConf' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So what your seeing is that the `SparkConf` isn't a java object, this is happening because its trying to use the `SparkConf` as the first parameter, if instead you do `sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)` it should use your configuration. That being said, you might be better of just starting a regular python program rather than stopping the default spark context & re-starting it, but you'll need to use the named parameter technique to pass in the conf object either way.

Comment: Thanks, I just missed it

Comment: So did I when I first took a look (unfortunately we can't easily do the same type tricks in Python that we can in Scala to its hard to match the API unless we add some really ugly code).

Answer (score 11):

update configuration in **Spark 2.3.1**

To change the default spark configurations you can follow these steps:

**Import the required classes**

```
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

**Get the default configurations**

```
spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()
```

**Update the default configurations**

```
conf = spark.sparkContext._conf.setAll([('spark.executor.memory', '4g'), ('spark.app.name', 'Spark Updated Conf'), ('spark.executor.cores', '4'), ('spark.cores.max', '4'), ('spark.driver.memory','4g')])
```

**Stop the current Spark Session**

```
spark.sparkContext.stop()
```

**Create a Spark Session**

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
```

Comment: This will **not** update the ```spark.driver.memory```. See this answer for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62799033/5140049

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to in-line modify spark settings for a given Spark Context require that the context be closed. For example:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
SparkContext.setSystemProperty('spark.driver.maxResultSize', '10g')
sc = SparkContext("local", "App Name")
```

source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/python-programming-guide.html

p.s. if you need to close the SparkContext just use:

```
SparkContext.stop(sc)
```

and to double check the current settings that have been set you can use:

```
sc._conf.getAll()
```