# How to read in multiple parquet files from S3 into a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, parquet, boto3

I'm trying to correctly read in a bunch of parquet files from an `s3` bucket into a dataframe for processing.  I'm using `boto3`, and I'm not quite sure how to get the data out, and then correctly `union` them together (if necessary).  Here is what I have tried:

```
# def distributedParquetRead(s3_key, bucket_name='instructure-canvas-logs'):
#     s3obj = b3.resource('s3').Object(
#         bucket_name=bucket_name,
#         key=s3_key
#     )
#     data_frame = sql_context.read.parquet(s3obj.get()['body'].read())
#     return data_frame

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s3 = b3.resource('s3')
    bucket_name = 'instructure-canvas-logs'
    log_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    key = r'access-canvas/parquet/year=2016/month=04/'
    keys = [s3_key.key for s3_key in log_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key)]
    s3 = b3.client('s3').get_object(
        Bucket=bucket_name,
        Key=keys[0]
    )
    df = sql_context.read.parquet(s3['Body'])
    df.select('user_id').show(1)
    # pkeys = sc.parallelize(keys)
    # data_frames = pkeys.flatMap(distributedParquetRead)
```

EDIT: As requested, here is the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mharris/Code/PycharmProjects/spark/canvas_logs/canvas_requests_logs.py", line 31, in <module>
    df = sql_context.read.parquet(s3['Body'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 205, in parquet
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 61, in _to_seq
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 798, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 785, in _get_args
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_collections.py", line 501, in convert
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 804, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/1.6.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 278, in get_command_part
AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'
`

Comment: Still am wondering about this.  You can use the `*` to read in a bunch of files using the `s3n://` uri in `EMR`, but the examples I've seen for efficient distributed file loading use something like `boto3`

Comment: Please, add exact stack trace into your question. It will tell us more context information about where the problem occurred (not sure it has problem to read the data form S3 or to parse the data). The first impression is, your way of reading from S3 is correct and shall provide the content.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I have added the traceback to the OP.

Comment: Great. Check the question [How to change SparkContext properties in Interactive PySpark session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362783/how-to-change-sparkcontext-properties-in-interactive-pyspark-session) which deals with the same type of error message. Does it help?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky I already have the `sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) line unfortunately:/