# How to set `spark.driver.memory` in client mode - pyspark (version 2.3.1)

Tags: python, pyspark, config

I'm new to PySpark and I'm trying to use *pySpark* (ver 2.3.1) on my local computer with *Jupyter-Notebook*.

I want to set *spark.driver.memory* to 9Gb by doing this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .master("local[2]") \
       .appName("test") \
       .config("spark.driver.memory", "9g")\
       .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()  # check the config
```

It returns

```
[('spark.driver.memory', '9g'),
('spark.driver.cores', '4'),
('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
('spark.driver.port', '15611'),
('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
('spark.app.name', 'test'),
('spark.executor.id', 'driver'),
('spark.submit.deployMode', 'client'),
('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true'),
('spark.master', 'local[2]'),
('spark.app.id', 'local-xyz'),
('spark.driver.host', '0.0.0.0')]
```

It's quite of weird because when I look at the document, it shows that

> Note: In **client mode**, this config **must not be set** through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file. [document here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/configuration.html)

But, as you see in the result above, it returns

> [('spark.driver.memory', '9g')

Even when I access to the **spark web UI** (on port *4040*, *environment* tab), it still shows 
[image]

I tried one more time, with `'spark.driver.memory', '10g'`. The *web UI* and `spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()` returned **'10g'**.
I'm so confused about that.
My questions are:

1. Is the document right about `spark.driver.memory` config
2. If the document is right, is there a proper way that I can check `spark.driver.memory` after config. I tried `spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()` as well as *Spark web UI* but it seems to lead to a wrong answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You provided the following code.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
       .master("local[2]") \
       .appName("test") \
       .config("spark.driver.memory", "9g")\ # This will work (Not recommended)
       .getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

> This config must not be set through the `SparkConf` directly

means you can set the driver memory, but it it is not recommended at **RUN TIME**. Hence, if you set it using `spark.driver.memory`, it accepts the change and overrides it. But, this is not recommended. So, that particular comment **this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly** does not apply in the documentation. You can tell the JVM to instantiate itself (JVM) with `9g` of driver memory by using `SparkConf`.

Now, if you go by this line (**Spark is fine with this**)

> Instead, please set this through the --driver-memory, it implies that

when you are trying to submit a `Spark` job against `client`, you can set the driver memory by using `--driver-memory` flag, say

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 12G
```

Now the line ended with the following phrase

> or in your default properties file.

You can tell `SPARK` in your environment to read the default settings from `SPARK_CONF_DIR` or `$SPARK_HOME/conf` where the `driver-memory` can be configured. **Spark is also fine with this.**

To answer your second part

> If the document is right, is there a proper way that I can check spark.driver.memory after config. I tried spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll() as well as Spark web UI but it seems to lead to a wrong answer."

I would like to say that the documentation is right. You can check the driver memory by using or eventually for what you have specified about `spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll()` works too.

```
>>> sc._conf.get('spark.driver.memory')
u'12g' # which is 12G for the driver I have used
```

To conclude about the documentation. You can set the `spark.driver.memory' in the

- `spark-shell`, `Jupyter Notebook` or any other environment where you already initialized `Spark` (**Not Recommended**).
- `spark-submit` command (**Recommended**)
- `SPARK_CONF_DIR` or `SPARK_HOME/conf` (**Recommended**)
- You can start `spark-shell` by specifying

  `spark-shell --driver-memory 9G`

For more information refer,

[Default Spark Properties File](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-properties.html)

Comment: Saying "This config must not be set through the SparkConf directly" is because it's not working by doing so. Saying "It's not recommended at runtime" implies that you can still do it and it will work, which is not.

Comment: As the doc says, it simply doesn't' work as Spark driver, which runs on JVM, already executed when the driver is doing something with the given configuration, so the driver can't fix its available memory unless it's killed and restarted with the new parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `spark.driver.memory` through `SparkSession.builder.config` **only works if the driver JVM hasn't been started before**.

To prove it, first run the following code against a fresh Python intepreter:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "512m").getOrCreate()
spark.range(10000000).collect()
```

The code throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` as 10M rows won't fit into 512m driver. However if you try that with 2g memory (again, with fresh Python interpreter):

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "2g").getOrCreate()
spark.range(10000000).collect()
```

the code works just fine. Now, you'd expect this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "512m").getOrCreate()
spark.stop()  # to set new configs, you must first stop the running session 
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "2g").getOrCreate()
spark.range(10000000).collect()
```

to run without errors, as your session's `spark.driver.memory` is seemingly set to 2g. However, you get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`, which means **your driver memory is still 512m!** The driver memory wasn't updated because the driver JVM was already started when it received the new config. Interestingly, if you read spark's config with `spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()` (or from Spark UI), it tells you your driver memory is 2g, which is obviously not true.

Thus the official spark documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/configuration.html#application-properties) is right when it says **you should set driver memory through the --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file**.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the documentation is correct. The memory needs to be specified before the JVM starts. After JVM starts, even if you change the value of the property programmatically inside the application, it won't reset the memory allocated by JVM. You can verify the driver memory allocated and used from Spark UI "Executors" tab.

> Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the
>   SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has
>   already started at that point.

[image]

Comment: Where exactly can I get the driver memory in Executors tab ? I tried but I couldnt find it there

Comment: Have a look at the image i posted. In the last table under header "Executor", there is a row "Executor ID = driver". That would tell you all the info abt the driver node.

Comment: Yes, I saw the tab but I didn't think the **driver memory** can be found there. The "Storage Memory = 1KB/384.1MB" just tells us about THE **Memory used / total available memory for storage of data like RDD partitions cached in memory**. And as far as I know, Memory management in Spark is currently broken down into two disjoint regions: one for **execution** (like Shuffle) and one for **storage** (Storage Memory).

Comment: Like OP, I'm new to worrying about PySpark memory-configuration issues. I'm currently dealing with memory-overhead constraints inside a Google Dataproc cluster initialized via an Airflow task. This answer helped me realize that instead of trying to modify the configuration at initialization of SparkSession (inside my pyspark script), I needed to specify appropriate properties for the DataprocClusterCreateOperator.