# Increase number of executors in jupyter/pyspark-notebook

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I've been working on a project with pyspark that requires more executors. Currently, I've been using this very handy image (jupyter/pyspark-notebook) that creates the Jypyter Notebook with the pyspark automatically. It is really easy to use.

My issue is that this image only creates one executor - storage memory of only 434.4 MiB.

Is there a way to create more executors for this docker image?

I've found a lot of docker-compose online that instantiate more executors, but they kind of do everything from scratch. I think doing everything from scratch looks like an overwork since this image works beautifully - but I'm open to it if no fast workaround is available.

This is my docker-compose file:

```
jupyter:
  container_name: jupyter_pyspark
  build: .
  ports: 
    - "8888:8888"
    - "4040:4040"
    - "4041:4041"
  environment: 
    - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
  volumes: 
    - ./work:/home/jovyan/work
  hostname: localhost
  command: "start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''"
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/pyspark-notebook

# Change to root user to install java 8
USER root
  
# Install requirements
# COPY requirements.txt ./
# RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# RUN rm -rf requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8088 8042 4040

USER $NB_UID
```

OBS: I've tried changing config variables, with no success. I guess I'll have to create more apps in the docker-compose, but I don't know how to connect them to this image.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession \
            .builder \
            .config(conf=sparkConf) \
            .master("local[*]") \
            .appName("appYou") \
            .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running with `master local[*]`, you're only starting up 1 single JVM which will contain both the driver and executor functionality. That means that the concept of a driver/executor are somewhat vague in this case. You won't be able to start up multiple executors: everything will happen inside of a single driver.

But you can still make your memory larger! To increase its memory, you'll need to change your `spark.driver.memory` configuration parameters.

You can do that in multiple ways, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53620273/15405732).

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you. By the way, is there any difference in using a Spark with 4g of memory against a Spark with two workers with 2g each? Just to better understand if I should try one of the sparks formats I've found with workers. I've learned that splitting jobs with workers make things faster. But I'm not sure if this concept is supposed to be used with multiple machines only or if splitting local memory into multiple workers would make things easier.

Comment: By the way, @Koedlt, I think the config ("spark.driver.memory") should go before defining the SparkSession. I was getting an error because of that. Just add this before conf: `conf = SparkConf()` and `conf.set("spark.driver.memory", '4g')`

Comment: Ahhh yes that is indeed true! Some configurations cannot be changed once the Sparksession has been started. I'll edit my answer :) Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: To answer your question on the 4g of memory vs 2g each: it will depend on your case but if you have the same total amount of cores, you'll have less communication overhead with less executors. If you're running on a single machine (so not in physical clusters) I would just recommend using master `local[*]` and then everything is inside of 1 JVM (again, less communication overhead).