# Apache Spark: Possible to load data from multiple endpoints with different credentials in one job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to load data from multiple object store endpoints (e.g. AWS S3 buckets), each with its own credentials, in one Spark job such that the data loads can be parallelized. Finally, the data from those sources shall be union-ed and aggregated. I was hoping to achieve that by spawning a separate Spark session per endpoint and configuring the respective SSL credentials in those sessions via `.conf.set()`.

The first thing I tried was moving the credentials' config to a new session:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName('test-1')
  .config('spark.jars.packages', '<my fs driver package>')
  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.my_fs.impl', '<my fs implementation class>')
  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.my_fs.impl', '<my afs implementation class>')
  .getOrCreate())

session = spark.newSession()
session.conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.my_fs.ssl.keystore.location', '<keystore location>')
session.conf.set('spark.hadoop.fs.my_fs.ssl.keystore.password', '<password>')
dataFile = 'my_fs://<endpoint url>/path/to/data.csv'
df = session.read.option('header', True).csv(dataFile)
df.show()
```

(We have our own filesystem driver implementation that provides an abstraction of various object stores that we use. It is built in a different department (plus IP reasons) so I cannot share any details about it.)

This results in a `java.io.IOException: Keystore location was not provided` exception in our driver implementation.

To make sure the filesystem works, I tried:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName('test-0')
  .config('spark.jars.packages', '<my fs driver package>')
  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.my_fs.impl', '<my fs implementation class>')
  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.my_fs.impl', '<my afs implementation class>')
  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.my_fs.ssl.keystore.location', '<keystore location>')
  .config('spark.hadoop.fs.my_fs.ssl.keystore.password', '<password>')
  .getOrCreate())

session = spark.newSession()
dataFile = 'my_fs://<endpoint url>/path/to/data.csv'
df = session.read.option('header', True).csv(dataFile)
df.show()
```

And this works just fine.

So my approach does not seem to work since the SSL credentials config obviously does not end up in the right place when setting it via the session's `.conf.set()` method... is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: yes, you cannot set certain configs after it has been created. A solution would be to use to a temporarty s3 location to store your data in one place and use it for final computation. Basically, create one SparkContext with SparkConf for one endpoint, get data and write to temp location and stop this SparkContext. Do this for all endpoints. Now that you have all your data located at one location. Load from there and do your computation. Of course this will work for batch computation but not for streaming ones.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702232/3238085

Comment: @user238607, that would defeat my purpose of parallelizing the data loads and of isolating the different buckets (at least at-rest).

Comment: First issue, have you got your workflow figured out? Is the current setup working without parallel load? It seems it doesn't because you couldn't from keystore. My approach could solve that. Also you can time as to how much time is spent in loading the data. I feel unless your data is in TBs, it should be pretty fast. Another solution would be to create another superuser which has read access to all the buckets and that will be provided to only you.

Comment: @user238607, yes, the "superuser" approach is what we came up with, too, and that will likely be the final solution. Plus access restrictions for the "superuser" such that only a given path is accessible on each bucket. I would still be interested to know whether it is at all possible in Spark to handle multiple credentials in one job.