# How to set properties in org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver pyspark databricks

Tags: pyspark, hive, databricks

I'm using `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` to read data form hive and I'm trying to pass this property:

```
hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names = false
```

in the config dict:

```py
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:hive2://{cluster_name}:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/hive2;http.header.Connection=close"

hive_cfg = {
    "url": jdbc_url,
    "driver": "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver",
    "user": storage_account_name,
    "password": storage_account_access_key,
    "inferSchema": True,
    # "query": query,
    "dbtable": "schema_name.table_name",
    "properties": {"hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names": "false"}
}

page_views_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(**hive_cfg).load()
```

or

`spark.conf.set("hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names", False)`

To remove table_name from the output columns:

`table_name.column_name -> column_name`

but it is not working:

[image]

I have a function to handle that already:

```py
def remove_table_name_prefix_in_column_name(df, columns):
    for col_name in columns:
        new_col_name = col_name.split(".")[1]
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(col_name, new_col_name)
    return df
```

It works but I have more properties I want to pass and I'm using this one to test if the driver is actually reading these properties, since it is not working I doubt it will read the other properties I have when I use them.

Is there something wrong on my config/properties or is there another way to set this properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the spark conf without restarting the session (or context?) AFAIK. So pass it on CLI, or put it in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark.conf`.

```
spark-shell --conf hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false
# or spark-submit --conf ...
```

You might also need to prefix the config name with `spark.` depending on what conf it is. Read [Custom Hadoop/Hive Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) in Spark config guide. So perhaps

```
spark-shell --conf spark.hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false
```

You can [restart your context and create a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51702232/496289), but can not update existing session/context.

Comment: Unfortunately where I work we are not allowed to use `spark-shell` or `spark-submit`. I tried using `spark.set('spark.hive.*')` didn't work. I also tried putting those configs in the hive-site.xml file. Nothing is working.

Comment: See all the ways in which you can set the config in docs, and pick the one applicable for your infra.